# How can my form elements resize when the window is resized?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

I have this form, with a tab control and a listbox inside:

[image]

When I resize the window's height, I get something like this:

[image]

However, I actually wanted the tab control and the listbox to resize along, having the following result:

[image]

I believe I could achieve this effect by just responding to some kind of `onResize()` method in the form, and do my own calculations to manually update the size of the tab control and the listbox accordingly.

However, I've seen many applications achieve this effect, so I suspect there is actually a better way to do so - perhaps a builtin feature.

Do you know a better way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a good tutorial that explains how to resize winform controls on resizing the container form control using the dock and anchor properties:

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/manage-winform-controls-using-the-anchor-and-dock-properties/6165908

Setting the four values of the anchor property(top,right,bottom,left), you can make your control's edges to stay stationary with respect to the Form control even when it is re-sized.

Comment: Links are not answers. Answers on SO are expected to be self-contained. Please [review this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/135887).

Comment: @Charles: Are you suggesting me to un-accept this answer? Curiously, I didn't have to see the tutorial (the phrase "anchor properties" did pretty much the job)

Comment: I have mentioned the necessary properties to be used(anchor and dock), if that still doesn't suffice sorry about that. Ill update the answer with relevant information in a while.

Comment: @Omega, oh no, if you found it useful, it's your job to mark it as the best answer.  It could just be *better* by being more than just a link to some external site that could decide to break all of their links (again) at any time.

Comment: @Charles: Ah, ok. Thanks you two for helping!

Answer (score 8):

You can use the anchor property of the tab control -- just anchor all four sides.

Answer (score 2):

This may help:

```
Private Sub frmMain_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.SizeChanged 'tab container sizechanged event
        tabMain.Dock = DockStyle.None 'set dock to none to allow resize
        tabMain.Size = New Size(New Point(3, 3)) ' set size anything you want
        tabMain.Dock = DockStyle.Fill 'set dock to fill to fit to container
    End Sub
```

Comment: You should explain what you are doing here.

Comment: tabMain is the tabControl.
frmMain is the Form containing tabControl.
Thats it easy!

Answer (score 1):

You Can use Dock property of Of Both Tab and listbox to be fill

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired result place the control how you want it to be in the standard size form. then use 
the Anchor property to Top, Bottom, Left, Right. this allow you to specify that you always want the control to be relatively positioned in the form based off of the smallest size.

I.E:
Set the anchor property to Top, Bottom, Left, Right this will ensure that the Top, Bottom, Left, Right edge of the control will always be the same distance from each edge regardless of the parents size.

If you want the control placed a specific distance from each edge of the control surface use Anchor Top, Bottom, Left, Right

if you want the control top and left edge locked 8 pixels from the top and left edge of the parent, set the Anchor Property to Top, Left the control will never resize it will always stay relatively positioned at 8,8.

Comment: @AlexKarshin: It's a property on the control. U can set it by right clicking the listbox control in the design view in Visual Studio and select properties.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `Dock` and `Anchor` properties to control how a component control is resized when its parent/container is resized.

To make a control fill its container, simply

```
theControl.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill
```

To retain some margins, set the `Anchor` property

```
theControl.Anchor = CType((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top _
    Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom _
    Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left _
    Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right), System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)
```

You can also set these properties in the Property tool window.

Answer (score 0):

Click on `tab 1` or `tab 2` Then on the side in the `Property Tab` look for the `Dock` property. Then select the one in the middle or type full.

Or

You can look for `Anchor` and select the `bottom tab`, the `top tag`, the `right tag`, and the `left tag`.

Hope This Helped!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code in the form load event...

```
TabControl1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
ListBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

This will Resize the controls when the form is also resized.

You may also use tableLayout Panel or anchor property of the controls to achive the same result.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I struggled a lot with the *anchor* and *dock* as I had many controls from other libraries and some of them did not have the anchor and dock properties, but this technique helped me. It dynamically sets the size of all the controls in the WinForm by referencing it with the *width* and *Height* property of the WinForm using the Resize event of that form. In the below code sample the form name is Main.

```
Dim CuRWidth As Integer = Me.Width
Dim CuRHeight As Integer = Me.Height

    Private Sub Main_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Resize
            Dim RatioHeight As Double = (Me.Height - CuRHeight) / CuRHeight
            Dim RatioWidth As Double = (Me.Width - CuRWidth) / CuRWidth

            For Each ctrl As Control In Controls
                ctrl.Width += ctrl.Width * RatioWidth
                ctrl.Left += ctrl.Left * RatioWidth
                ctrl.Top += ctrl.Top * RatioHeight
                ctrl.Height += ctrl.Height * RatioHeight
            Next

            CuRHeight = Me.Height
            CuRWidth = Me.Width
End Sub
```

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVi1ve5qHXA